# Control and/or monitor who does data exports from salesforce

Tags: reporting, security, data-export

besides our Sales department doesn't have the Export Report option they can still ctrl+C -> ctrl+V into an excel sheet if they wanted to take some information for other companies or whatever.

I assume I can control in a visualforce page via Javascript if someone performs a ctrl+C , but there's some way I could do this on Standard reports page? Or some way to ensure nobody takes info outside salesforce?
And for every security measure I think we could make there comes out plenty of options to cross through it.

Does someone know some way to prevent this from happening or it's just too unrealistic?

Comment: Even if they can't copy it, they can manually type it out. If they can view, they can take the data with them.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I mean, if they want, they will, that's my point of view, but high ranks are concerned about this and I have to give them a I reliable answer. I'm pretty sure it sounds like a pretty dumb question, as much as it sounds to miself. But I just want to ensure i'm not missing anything.

Comment: This has the makings of a fool's errand. What about Excel s/s passed around by email?  How are you going to lock those down?

Answer (score 1):

You might find the paid [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) feature useful.

> Event monitoring can be used with 32 different file types:
>
> - Apex Callout
> - Apex Execution
> - Apex SOAP
> - Apex Trigger
> - API
> - **Async Report**
> - Bulk API
> - Change Set Operation
> - Content Distribution
> - Content Document Link
> - Content Transfer
> - Dashboard
> - Document Attachment Downloads
> - Login
> - Login As
> - Logout
> - MDAPI Operation
> - Multiblock Report
> - Package Install
> - Queued Execution
> - **Report**
> - **Report Export**
> - REST API
> - Salesforce1 Adoption (UI Tracking)
> - Sandbox
> - Sites
> - Time-Based Workflow
> - URI
> - Visualforce
> - Wave Change
> - Wave Interaction
> - Wave Performance

Comment: N.B. - I believe this is a $$ option for all but DE orgs - `Log files are available based on CreatedDate for the last 30 days when organizations purchase User Event Monitoring or one day for Developer Edition organizations`

Comment: Yeah good point. I meant to include that in my original post but seem to have left it off.